# Where does Identity Server 4 stores client's code verifier

Tags: identityserver4

I have setup Identity Server 4 with EF & Angular client (OIDC JS library) with Authorization Code with PKCE grant. I see the code challenge & method being passed in the /authorize url. As per specification, auth server stores code challenged passed by client on auth server to be verified later when client sends code verifier.
Where does identity server 4 stores the code challenge in database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how it is implemented, one common way is to store them in a database table called **PersistedGrants**. The **Authorization Codes** are also stored in this table, however they are deleted as as soon as they are used.

The image shows what it can look like in this table.
[image]

The Code_challenge is stored together with the access-code in the database and you can see the code where they pack it all together and then store it as an encrypted blob in the database.

- [AuthorizeResponseGenerator.cs](https://github.com/DuendeSoftware/IdentityServer/blob/main/src/IdentityServer/ResponseHandling/Default/AuthorizeResponseGenerator.cs) (look at the end of the file)

The **authorization code** is stored in the database as the image below shows:
[image]

The actual payload is encrypted and protected, at it looks like this:

```
{
  "PersistentGrantDataContainerVersion": 1,
  "DataProtected": true,
  "Payload": "CfDJ8OFLAj3iVVVHvhgvjcKB19Z7-Hms4IIQobGgGl7VnJQCtKiB-Inr3h-mcWCxxD8dJ4QNTbuVeywbT6ROsaf13EpaIQDWtLgbnSPvCDTLQeWTO_vP0UtDwJ7TTCc5aTvKEp_9hX9S1b3l685bmBMlTIcZFqGGM2VfK0qasWCqKSQcTxeN6cgJygZEQNMgAG4ipqr..."
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the use of this table. My question is about the method mentioned in this document. Point#4.6 If IS4 has to verify the PKCE upon roundtrip, where does it stores the code challenge? https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7636#section-4.6

Comment: I have set EnableTokenCleanup to false. Still, I can see only refresh_token in my db. authorization_code record is not present. Is it removed immediately?

Comment: Yes! It only is in he database for less than a second. If you try to do a manual authentication using postman or curl, then you can see it. Some other ways to see it is to start the SQL-Server profiler, you can enable the SQL-logs, you can set a breakpoint in the storage layer (PersistedGrantStore...)....